# Storing credentials to run PowerShell script in PHP application (remotely)

Tags: php, security, powershell, passwords

I'm running a Windows 2012 R2 server with XAMPP (php/mysql/apache) and PowerShell v3.  For the past couple of months, my code has been working just fine to store and retrieve an encrypted password

My questions is, how can I store a password to be used by my Powershell scripts? The scripts work fine when I run then locally, but when I run them from a PHP app on a remote client, I get a "The server has rejected the client credentials." error.

I've tried creating a password file this way:

```
$File = "D:\path\to\password.txt"
[Byte[]] $key = (1..16)
$Password = "myPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $key | Out-File $File
```

And retrieving and using it like this:

```
$PasswordFile = "D:\path\to\password.txt"
[Byte[]] $key = (1..16)
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "domain\username", (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)
```

Then using it like this:

```
get-wmiobject Win32_Service -ComputerName $dc.name -credential $credential | select systemname,name,startmode,caption,state
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-credentials-how-to-encrypt-a-password/) the use slightly different commands

Maybe you want to try their way

```
$SecureString = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$EncryptedPW = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $SecureString
Set-Content -Path "C:\tmp\mypw.txt" -Value $EncryptedPW
```

and retrieve with

```
$EncryptedPW = Get-Content -Path "C:\tmp\mypw.txt"
$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $EncryptedPW
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "User", $SecureString
```

I didn't try it yet. But it worth a shot.